# Changing permissions on child folders in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a DLL to change permissions on a folder and everything underneath the folder. Below is the code that I have right now.

The problem comes when I call addPermissions(). It's correctly setting the permissions on the dirName folder and any folder that I later create under dirName, but any folder that exists when I add permissions doesn't get the additional permissions.

Do I need to recursively set the permissions on all child folders? Or is there a way to do this with a line or two of code?

```
public class Permissions
{
    public void addPermissions(string dirName, string username)
    {
        changePermissions(dirName, username, AccessControlType.Allow);
    }

    public void revokePermissions(string dirName, string username)
    {
        changePermissions(dirName, username, AccessControlType.Deny);
    }

    private void changePermissions(string dirName, string username, AccessControlType newPermission)
    {
        DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);

        DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

        string user = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + username;

        myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
            user, 
            FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.Write | FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile | FileSystemRights.Delete, 
            InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, 
            PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, 
            newPermission
        ));

        myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it recursively. You can specify inheritance rules for new folders/files but for existing you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I was searching for a quick & easy solution to do this and couldn't believe that there really is no "automatic way" to do this. After spending quite some time on Stackoverflow, I came to the conclusion that unfortunately you are right. ;-)
I finally found this "manual recursion" solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289950/recursive-security-settings/1296003#1296003

Answer (score 5):

This question is old but I was looking for the same thing and found a solution:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);
var dirSecurity = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

// Add the DirectorySystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
    account, 
    rights, 
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, 
    PropagationFlags.None, 
    AccessControlType.Allow));

// Set the new access settings.
dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
```

greetings

Comment: -1: I don't see how this addresses the question. It looks like this code is doing the same thing as stated in the question, and doesn't update permissions of existing files/directories.

Comment: It does what the OP asked for, since I have tried it and you obviously haven't, I will hereby humbly ask you to zip it.

Comment: I did test this, but it wasn't working for me. When I have some time I will come back and figure out what the difference was.